# ProFTPd on 14.04 - 503 Error

Tags: bash, ftp, proftpd

Config file is nice and simple, I'm not asking too much of ProFTPd and I have set required parameters.

```
    ServerName          “uk.domain.com"
ServerType          standalone
DefaultServer           on

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                21

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask               022

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd).
MaxInstances            30

# Set the user and group under which the server will run.
User                nobody
Group               nogroup

# To cause every FTP user to be "jailed" (chrooted) into their home
# directory, uncomment this line.
DefaultRoot ~

# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
<Directory />
  AllowOverwrite        on
</Directory>
```

The user has /bin/bash shell set. ProFTPd is in default nobody, nogroup etc. Port TDP and UDP is open on 21, inbound and outbound. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

There are no directives defined in your configuration. You need to create some directives for Proftp to use. The man page will help with this.

Here's the configuration you're looking for:

```
## Includes required DSO modules. This is mandatory in proftpd 1.3
# Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf

# To really apply changes reload proftpd after modifications.
AllowOverwrite on
AuthAliasOnly on
AuthPam on    # Uses unix authentication.

UserAlias userftp connor     # UserAlias *loginuser* *real user*
ServerName                      "uk.domain.com"
ServerType                      standalone
DeferWelcome                    on

MultilineRFC2228 on
DefaultServer                   on
ShowSymlinks                    off

TimeoutNoTransfer 600
TimeoutStalled 100
TimeoutIdle 2200

DisplayChdir                    .message
ListOptions                     "-l"

RequireValidShell               off

TimeoutLogin 20

RootLogin                       off

# It's better for debug to create log files ;-)
ExtendedLog                     /var/log/ftp.log
TransferLog                     /var/log/xferlog
SystemLog                       /var/log/syslog.log

#DenyFilter                     \*.*/

# I don't choose to use /etc/ftpusers file (set inside the users you want to ban, not useful for me)
UseFtpUsers off

# Allow to restart a download
AllowStoreRestart               on

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port, so you may prefer to use another port for security reasons (choose here the port you want)
Port                            21

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances 8

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User                  nobody
Group                 nogroup

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new files and dirs
# (second parm) from being group and world writable.
Umask                           022     022

PersistentPasswd                off

MaxClients 8
MaxClientsPerHost 8
MaxClientsPerUser 8
MaxHostsPerUser 8

# Display a message after a successful login
AccessGrantMsg "welcome !!!"
# This message is displayed for each access good or not
ServerIdent                  on       "Already home"

# Lock all the users in home directory
DefaultRoot ~

MaxLoginAttempts    5

#VALID LOGINS
<Limit LOGIN>
AllowUser connor    # Must be *real* user
DenyALL
</Limit>

<Directory /home/>
Umask 022 022
AllowOverwrite on
        <Limit MKD STOR DELE XMKD RNEF RNTO RMD XRMD READ RMD>
          DenyAll
        </Limit>
        <Limit STOR CWD MKD>
          AllowAll
        </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I set /home as the directives but it wouldn't login. I want the user to have completed FTP control. Any help?

Comment: Do you have an updated config file you can insert here?

Comment: I don't im afraid bud. Thanks for the quick reply.

Would you be able to assist me with a URL with one? Or is it all easily to read on the proftpd website KB?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/48q8ax7J - I can't seem to paste the config settings into comments

Comment: According to your config file, you have multiple /home/ directives that could be conflicting with each other. Instead of having multiples condense them into one directive. You can have multiple <LIMIT> inside the one directive. Also, from what I can see you're denying all access with the DENY ALL option. Check you permissions as well. Umask takes away current permissions. For instance, if your /home directory has a mask of 755 and Umask is set to 022, then the current permissions set will be 733.

Comment: Hey, thanks again! I've edited the config and made only one /home/ directives with all functions allowed (I'll work back from there). I set the config and restarted the proftpd server but to no avail!

Please find updated config - http://pastebin.com/FiqCFYLQ
Still returning 503 login error :/